# Wordpress Plugin Development: Add existing Pages to a Nav Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a hard time trying to programatically add existing pages to an existing nav menu.

```
wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array('menu-item-title' => $page['Title'],
                                       'menu-item-object' => 'page',
                                       'menu-item-object-id' => $pid,
                                       'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
                                       'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
```

I'm not getting an error in response, but the pages do not get added to the menu.  What am I missing?

UPDATE [FIXED]:

```
wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, $args);
$args = array(
        'menu-item-title' => $post['post_title'],
        'menu-item-object' => 'page',
        'menu-item-object-id' => $pid,
        'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
        'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
        'menu-item-parent-id' => $navParentID,
        'menu-item-position' => $post['menu_order']
 );
```

Menu order was apparently required to make this work.

Comment: There's a checkbox on the Appearance > Menus options that says  "Automatically add new top-level pages" which should get you most of the way there.  If that doesn't do it, check this example out:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44736/programmatically-add-a-navigation-menu-and-menu-items

Comment: Hi Tammy,
Thanks for the response, but the goal was to programmatically add pages to the menu while importing them from an external source, but not to add ALL new pages to the menu.  I was able to find a solution and will post my updates above.

Comment: Hey @bookt-jacob - curious if you could post a more detailed answer.  All of your coe is good for me except that I can't tell where `$navParentID` is defined.  I'm trying to figure out how to get set that parameter dynamically.  I'm sure that ID is not the same as the ID for the page of the parent nav item is it?